# iOS: UILabel dynamic height using sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uilabel

I am trying to give my `UILabel` dynamic height so that my layout of other labels looks correct in both landscape and portrait.

In portrait, my text wraps to the second line, in landscape it does not.  So, when using `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` I get the same height when rotating both ways, when I had assumed it would be a larger number when the text was 2 lines.

How can I get the height of my `UILabel` when it has two lines of text or more (portrait) and get the new height which is one line, when in landscape?

I guess I am not understanding how to get dynamic height working...

```
UILabel *itemTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, top, screen.size.width - 20, 200.0f)];
itemTitle.text = self.newsAsset.title;
itemTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
itemTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
itemTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
itemTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
itemTitle.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
itemTitle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
itemTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
itemTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
itemTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
[itemTitle sizeToFit];

// Set the height
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300,9999);
CGSize titleSize = [itemTitle.text sizeWithFont:itemTitle.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:itemTitle.lineBreakMode];

NSLog(@"Height: %.f  Width: %.f", titleSize.height, titleSize.width);

//Adjust the label the the new height
CGRect newFrame = itemTitle.frame;
newFrame.size.height = titleSize.height;
itemTitle.frame = newFrame;

// Add them!
[headerView addSubview:itemTitle];
[itemTitle release];

top += titleSize.height;
```

Comment: what are you passing as the `constrainedToSize:` argument? can we see some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the line where you set `maximumLabelSize` to

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(headerView.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
```

Comment: How would you do this without setting a hard-coded value of 9999?

Comment: `CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(headerView.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);`

Or whatever number you want as a maximum height.

Answer (score 0):

In your code as it is now, in either orientation you will get the same width and height, since you always pass a width of 300 to the `sizeWithFont` method. If you make it dynamic, maybe the result of the `sizeWithFont` will also change dynamically.

Comment: Ok, and so what would I do to fix this?

Comment: maybe use `screen.size.width - 20` instead of 300, like you do in the alloc/init line? And I would also NSLog() anything that may be of interest, e.g. `NSLog(@"screen size: %@",NSStringFromCGSize(screen.size));`

Comment: (just to make sure that the screen orientation change does in fact result in the flipped screen size at that point)