# Creating flexible UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I got an app with some text data.

From TableView user choose one cell and then see UIViewController with relative text data. But information text could be from 1 line to N. How can create such UILabel, which will change size depending on size of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to do this inside the code, with the sizeWithFont method.
you can find more info here: [iOS: UILabel dynamic height using sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545275/855738)

If it's the height that varies, you could set a maximum label size, with your standard label width and 9999 height, and then check what the suggested size would be for your text, using the font of your label

Answer (score 3):

In the NSString UIKit Additions, you can find the following method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

with this one you can define the optimal height or width of your label. For example, to get the optimal height of a UILabel, you can create a category on UILabel with the following method:

```
- (float)optimalHeight
{
    return [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, UINTMAX_MAX) lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode].height;
}
```

after that, you can simply change the frame of your UILabel. Don't forget to set the number of line of your label to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the label's `numberOfLines` property to specify how many lines it can wrap to.  If you set it to zero, it can wrap to any number of lines.  You can set this property in your nib.

However, you also need to set its frame large enough to show all of the lines.  The easiest way is to send it the `sizeToFit` message after you set its text.  It will keep its width (I think) but change its height to be tall enough to display all of its lines after wrapping.

If you might have so much text that it doesn't fit on the screen (or doesn't fit in the space available for your label), you should use a `UITextView` instead.  A `UITextView` allows scrolling automatically.

Comment: can i set fix width for that label? and then take height?

Comment: check out [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406212/sizing-a-uilabel-to-fit)